# Confusion regarding Kelvin functions

Tags: special-functions, intuition, matlab, bessel-functions

I am trying to implement the following equation from [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7869720) and having some troubles in the interpretation of $bei'$ and $ber'$. I understand from the [definition of Kelvin functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_functions) that for integers n, $ber_n(x)$ can be defied, and usually, $bei(x)$ means $bei_0(x)$. I can compute it using [Matlab function](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65336-kelvins-functions).

> [image]

**What is the usual interpretation of $bei'$ and $ber'$ ? is it  $bei_1(x)$ and $ber_1(x)$ or is it the derivative?** It appears that it is very common notation and not explained in the paper (I could not find anywhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: $\operatorname{bei}(x)$ means $\operatorname{bei}_0(x)$ and not $\operatorname{ber}_0(x)$.

Second: 
$\operatorname{bei}'(x)$ is the derivative of $\operatorname{bei}(x)$ and not $\operatorname{bei}_1(x)$ but the  derivatives can be expressed with  the first order function, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.63.E3

$$\operatorname{ber}'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big( \operatorname{ber}_1(x) + \operatorname{bei}_1(x)\Big)$$
$$\operatorname{bei}'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big( \operatorname{bei}_1(x) - \operatorname{ber}_1(x)\Big)$$

Comment: Great! Thank you. Initial one was a typo. Do you know any book or a research paper which has the expansion of derivatives?

Comment: What kind of expansion? You can differentiate the expansions of the original functions, the section [Basic properties](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.68.ii) shows some relations, the Wolfram Function Site [1](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/KelvinBei/20/02/) and [2](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/KelvinBer/20/02/) gives expansions in hypergeometric and other functions. There are polynomial approximations in [Abramowitz/Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_384.htm).

Comment: (continued) My own Pascal implementation uses the term-wise derivatives of the following expansions: Abramowitz/Stegun 9.9.10 if $x \le 20$ and 9.10.1/2 for $x > 20$.

Comment: Got it! thank you.